# Create installation file for Linux on Windows

Tags: c++, linux

I have a question: I got a C++ project with OpenCV and I need to create an installation file to install it on Linux, is there any chance to do it on Windows?
I already created *.exe file to install my program on Windows, but I'm not very familiar with Linux system :/
Is there maybe any program for Windows to create installation file for Linux?

Comment: Cross compile. E.g. MinGW with an appropriate cross compiler toolchain could be appropriate.

Comment: To be honest, cross-compilation compilation always give me so much trouble that it's only really worth it when there is no real alternative (android, embedded, etc.). I even prefer making a virtual machine and building it there to setting up a cross-compilation environment.